# Como retornar mais de uma coluna da mesma tabela?

Tags: php, mysql, query

Com esta SQL eu consigo no meu banco de dados selecionar e agrupar produtos por variações que seriam neste caso diferentes atributos para o mesmo produto.

Assim, ao gerar a view do produto, eu tenho um dropdown no produto com todos os atributos podendo o cliente escolher num maior número de possibilidades para o mesmo produto, por exemplo um carro que tem várias cores.

Eis a ***SQL***:

```
$BuscaProdutosAtivos = $pdo->prepare("SELECT tbl_produtos.*, tbl_categorias.*,
                                      GROUP_CONCAT(tbl_variacoes.valor) AS Variacoes FROM tbl_variacoes
                                      INNER JOIN tbl_produtos ON tbl_produtos.id = tbl_variacoes.cod_prod  
                                      INNER JOIN tbl_categorias ON tbl_produtos.prod_categoria = tbl_categorias.cat_id
                                      GROUP BY (tbl_produtos.id)");
```

Com esta ***SQL*** eu retorno da `tbl_variacoes` a coluna `valor`. Eu gostaria de retornar `valor`, `dimensao`, `quantidade` pois estas três informações serão concatenadas dentro do dropdown formando ***uma variação***. Como posso fazer isso usando esta ***SQL***?

Eu imaginei que se pudesse usar diversos `GROUP_CONCAT` mas pesquisando em alguns lugares vi que não deve ser feito dessa forma.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cada vez que você usa um `GROUP_CONCAT` para [algo que precisa quebrar depois](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41987/como-transformar-uma-string-em-um-select-com-php), 100 pessoas morrem de Ebola na África.

Comment: Falando sério agora, pode ser o caso de fazer queries separadas para pegar essas "variações". Para responder mais precisamente eu precisaria ver um exemplo do que você quer colocar no tal dropdown.

Comment: Ou simplesmente concatenar essas coisas no PHP, não no MySQL. Não está dando pra entender bem a pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não entendi realmente o que você queria retornar, mas segue dois exemplos:

```
SELECT tbl_produtos.*, tbl_categorias.*, 
tbl_variacoes.valor || tbl_variacoes.dimensao || tbl_variacoes.quantidade AS Variacoes 

FROM tbl_variacoes

INNER JOIN tbl_produtos 
ON tbl_produtos.id = tbl_variacoes.cod_prod  

INNER JOIN tbl_categorias 
ON tbl_produtos.prod_categoria = tbl_categorias.cat_id
```

Ou

```
SELECT tbl_produtos.*, tbl_categorias.*, 
tbl_variacoes.valor, tbl_variacoes.dimensao, tbl_variacoes.quantidade

FROM tbl_variacoes

INNER JOIN tbl_produtos 
ON tbl_produtos.id = tbl_variacoes.cod_prod  

INNER JOIN tbl_categorias 
ON tbl_produtos.prod_categoria = tbl_categorias.cat_id
```