# Como transformar uma string em um select com PHP?

Tags: php, html

Depois de uma ***SQL*** eu tenho como retorno este registro:

```
// Dados
$cores = "amarelo, branco, azul, verde";
```

Gostaria de montar um select aonde fosse apresentado o conteúdo de `$cores` da seguinte forma:

```
<select name="">
    <option value="amarelo">amarelo</option>
    <option value="branco">branco</option>
    <option value="azul">azul</option>
    <option value="verde">verde</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Você está usando alguma framework ou PHP puro? Pode utilizar `echo`s para gerar o HTML?

Comment: Estou usando PHP puro !!!

Comment: Use um [explode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php) seguido de um loop mondando o html...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) para transformar a string em um array, é necessario passar um delimitador que nesse caso é `,`(virgula). Se o valor da descrição for o mesmo do `value`, basta colocar o valor da variável apenas entre `<option></option>`.

```
<?php
$cores = "amarelo, branco, azul, verde";

$arr = explode(',', $cores);

echo '<select name="cores">';
foreach($arr as $item){
    echo '<option>'. trim($item) .'</option>';
}

echo '</select>';
```

[**Exemplo com form**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/97s8-4cie)

Comment: Recomendo dar explode só na virgula, e usar um `trim`, assim caso fuja do padrão `, ` ainda funcionará...

Comment: @KaduAmaral obrigado pela suguestão, alterei a resposta como você falou.

Comment: Alguém consegue me ajudar aqui >>> http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41972/como-retornar-mais-de-uma-coluna-da-mesma-tabela